# Converting an aggregated series into a dataframe for later manipulation

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to work with data after I've aggregated it into a series with other dataframes.  I've over a decade experience in SQL, but I'm new to PANDAS and I find it terribly frustrating that such a simple request seems to have a very complex solution.

What I want to do in SQL is:

```
Select UniqueID, MinDate, DollarValue
From {select UniqueID, Min(date) as MinDate
       from DateTable 
       Join SalesTable
      Where DateTable.ServerTime < SalesTable.DateTime
     } as MinDateTable
     join SalesTable
Where MinDate between '2017-01-07 00:00:00'
                  and '2017-01-10 00:00:00
```

What I have in my Jupyter Notebook:

```
 # Import the configparser library
import configparser

 # Import database stuff
import pymysql
import psycopg2

 # Import pandas and numpy - the python data science magical libraries.
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

DateTable = pd.read_sql(SQL, dbConn)
SalesTable = pd.read_sql(dwQuery, dwConn)
merged_df=DateTable.merge(SalesTable,left_on=['UniqueID'],right_on=['UniqueID'],how='inner')
merged_df[merged_df['server_time'] < merged_df['Datetime']]
gb = merged_df.groupby(['UniqueID', 'Datetime'])
```

This gives me the MinDateTable subquery equivalent marvelously, but then I need to rejoin it on the SalesTable to get the dollars that happened before the server event timestamp and gb is a series, not a dataframe.

Here is my attempt to convert the series to a dataframe:

```
gb.apply(lambda x: x['server_time'].set_index())
gb_agg = gb.agg({'server_time' : np.max})
gb_agg.apply(lambda x: x.count())
```

Which throws an error on the first line:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Yet the Set_index is standardly stated in other posts as the way to turn a series into a DataFrame.

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 1):

```
gb.to_frame()
```

should turn it to a Dataframe.

Comment: I get this error when I try that:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'